# How to apply clothes to an armature

Tags: modeling, armature

I have a modeled person that has an armature and I created a T-Shirt for it in rest position now I need to figure out how to put the shirt on the model in pose mode.

[image]
[image]

I followed Den Den's instructions and get this:

[image]

Comment: Sometimes I think for tight fits it's easiest to use your body mesh, dupe it, scale it up ever so slightly, make a couple of loop cuts where sleeves collar etc go and delete  the rest. ( Or just select on mesh and extrude slightly.)  Then your weights and armature modifier are already set up.

Comment: See that's what did to create my shirt but none of the armature modifiers seem to effect the shirt

Comment: As well as the armature modifier the shirt shoujld also be a child of the rig, just like the body.  And is it green because it's part of a group or is there physics involved?

Answer (score 2):

1. Select armature and enter pose mode;
2. Select bones that are close to your cloth - in your case chest, neck, collarbone, etc. No legs and such;
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd>, then <kbd>H</kbd>;
4. Select character mesh;
5. Select cloth;
6. Enter weight paint mode;
7. Push *Transfer Weights* and use options as below:

[image]

In blender 2.8+, the "transfer weights" option is in weight paint/weights (top left of screen)/transfer weights
[image]

Comment: I followed and ended up with an extremely warped t shirt.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up just putting the armature into pose position and readjusting the vertices to make the shirt fit onto the model.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:
Create one more mesh enveloping your character and T-Shirt. (or T-Shirt only)
Next, you Transfer Weights to this mesh
Then, with MeshDeform modifier, you bind the body of the character and the T-Shirt (or T-Shirt only)

Comment: Would be good if you could add further explanation of *how* the user should use the 'Transfer Weights' and the 'MeshDeform' modifier.

Answer (score 0):

Delete all the existing vertex groups/armature mods from the shirt and put the character in it's default pose position. Apply the Mirror Modifier if present. Then follow these steps:

1. Select the shirt in object mode.
2. In the Modifiers panel, select "Add Modifier", select "Data Transfer".
3. In the Data Transfer panel, choose your character and the Source Object, check the "Vertex Data" box, then click the "Vertex Group" button, and then click the "Generate Data Layers" button at the bottom. I usually move this modifier to the top of the stack and once I'm satisfied it works, I'll apply it.
4. Add an Armature modifier to the shirt and select the character's armature in the panel. I usually like to move the Armature mod all the way to the top of the stack and any sub-d mods to the very bottom for best performance.